# dracoDecoderPath is not getting defined in gltf registerSystem in React

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am working with A-frame + reactjs and
I am defining the path of dracoDecoderPath in a-scene but in the registersystem, the path is taken as Default.
How can I resolve this issue??

A-Frame Version: 1.2.0
Platform / Device: Web / PC and phone
Reproducible Code Snippet or URL:

```
<a-scene shadow="type:pcfsoft" gltf-model="dracoDecoderPath: https://xyz.in/draco/" loading-screen="enabled:false" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" renderer="colorManagement:true; sortObjects: true; physicallyCorrectLights: true; maxCanvasWidth: 1920; maxCanvasHeight: 1920;" fog="type: linear; color: #e5eeff; far: 350; near: 0;density:1" physics="debug: true" ></a-scene>
```

Comment: Do you have an example (like a glitch)?